# Xcode Project Migration: .xcodeproj converted to a folder?

Tags: xcode, migration, project

I am trying to migrate my Xcode projects to a new computer, but the .xcodeproj keeps getting converted to a floder containing a .mode1v3 file, a pbxuser file and a pbxproj file. I tried moving the projects in archive but got the same results. Has anyone had to do this?

Also, against my wishes, the new computer was set up as a new computer instead of doing a full migration at the very beginning, so I got hosed on this being a painless migration.

Comment: It's not "converted" - the .xcodeproj bundle actually is a folder, which just *looks* like a file in the Finder. Ideally you should transfer over a network or via an HFS medium. If you go via e.g. an MS-DOS memory stick then you'll lose meta data.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for weighing in on this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the new computer have Xcode? Has it run Xcode before?

You can always click on **MyProject.xcodeproj**, choose Get Info and in **Open with:** section, manually choose Xcode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I unzipped the archives after running XCode for the first time and that did the trick. Thank goodness I asked! I would have tried just about everything else!

Answer (score 4):

XCode project file is actually a folder which is treated specially if XCode is installed. You can always control click on the project file and reveal the files in finder. If you install XCode on new machine then you will find that folder is treated correctly by XCode.